# Change Fragment contentView in android

Tags: android

I have a fragment the contains a list , now this fragment hold's `listView` that it data get from a `webserver` i want to display a loading view until the data come to the adapter . how can i change the contentView of a fragment ?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve done this by using a RelativeLayout that contains the ListView and the ProgressBar, where the ProgressBar is set to be `View.INVISIBLE`. Before retrieving data from the web server that ProgressBar should me made visible. When the data arrived just populate the ListView and make the ProgressBar invisible again.

Layout:

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Code:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// retrieve data ...
// populate ListView
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```